# Grails 2.5.4 WAR packaging error

Tags: grails, war, grails-2.0

I am trying to build a war from a grails 2.5.4 project but I am getting an error.

```
.Error 
|
WAR packaging error: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Here is the command I ran and the full trace.

```
grails dev war --plain-output --stacktrace --verbose

Base Directory: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio
|Loading Grails 2.5.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
..................................................
|Compiling 4 GSP files for package [biblio]
..
|Compiling 2 GSP files for package [springSecurityCore]
.    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage
.
|Building WAR file
     [copy] Copying 406 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage
     [copy] Copied 121 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage
...............    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/plugins/resources-1.2.14
.     [copy] Copying 7 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/plugins/resources-1.2.14
..........     [copy] Copying 5 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/grails-app
     [copy] Copied 4 empty directories to 1 empty directory under /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/grails-app
.     [copy] Copying 659 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
.     [copy] Copying 1354 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
.    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/spring
..     [copy] Copying 3 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
.     [copy] Copying 152 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/lib
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF
.   [delete] Deleting: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/resources/web.xml
.     [copy] Copying 4 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/lib
...[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/mongodb-5.0.12.RELEASE
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/mongodb-5.0.12.RELEASE
..    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/cache-1.1.8
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/cache-1.1.8
...    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/webxml-1.4.1
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/webxml-1.4.1
...    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/resources-1.2.14
.     [copy] Copying 2 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/resources-1.2.14
..     [copy] Copying 2 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
.    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-cas-2.0-RC1
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-cas-2.0-RC1
...    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-core-2.0-RC4
.     [copy] Copying 11 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-core-2.0-RC4
...    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-ldap-2.0.1
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-ldap-2.0.1
...    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/ldap-0.8.2
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/ldap-0.8.2
...    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/xss-sanitizer-0.4.0
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/xss-sanitizer-0.4.0
..     [copy] Copying 2 files to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
.    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/quartz-1.0.1
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/quartz-1.0.1
...    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/codenarc-0.25.2
.     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/codenarc-0.25.2
....   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/anupshrestha/workspaces/biblio/target/work/stage
.Error 
|
WAR packaging error: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities:

1. First try to restart your IDE

*Not solved?* Check below steps:

When we run `compile` or create `war` command it create files and stores them by default in the project's working directory. Where default directory name is `target`

If our project workspace contains previously created war. It will not deleted automatically. It will overwritten with new.

SO run the `clean` command and check the contents of the target directory. If still you notice that `target/work` directory still exists. 
run `clean-all` command and now check `target/work` are deleted or not.

Now try to create `war`

If still getting issue then exclude particular classes or jars which cause to create war

Hope this help's you

Comment: I am still getting the issue. I don't understand why the War script is deleting the staging directory before building the war?

Comment: @anupshrestha have you checked with `grails prod war` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with message:

```
| Error WAR packaging error: /Users/xxx/.grails/2.5.3/projects/my-proyect/resources/grails-app does not exist.
```

The error was caused by removing i18n directory.  Fix is to re-instate the i18n directory and add an empty messages.properties file.

[Reference](https://github.com/AtlasOfLivingAustralia/generic-hub/issues/3)